# Expect script to multiple devices stops if one login fails

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm attempting to write a small bash script with some embedded Expect scripting. I need to change around 3500 switch's hostnames. I have a csv file with my ip addresses and new hostnames, and my expect script. The script seems to run just fine, if there is no problem connecting to a switch. If I do get a "timeout" or "access denied" from a switch, the script will stop just exit. I need the script to go to the next ip address.

I do make use of rancid clogin for my automated logins.

I am new to expect and bash, and have search my best friend "google" for possible answers, but could not find an answer.

The script is as follows:

**hostnames.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# Set variables
set DATE [exec date +%F]
set timeout 10
# Log results
log_file -a hostnames-$DATE.log

# Let's go to configure mode

## Read the file
set fid [open ./hostnames.csv]
set content [read $fid]
close $fid

## Split into records on newlines
set records [split $content "\n"]

## Iterate over the records
foreach rec $records {

## Split into fields on comma
set fields [split $rec ","]

## Assign fields to variables and print some out...
lassign $fields\  hostname newname

puts "$hostname"
puts "$newname"

if {$hostname == ""} continue


# Announce which device we are working on and at what time
send_user "\n"
send_user ">>>>> Working on $hostname @ [exec date] <<<<<\r"
send_user "\n"

spawn clogin "$hostname\r"

expect {
    timeout  { send_user "\n Failed to get login prompt\n"; exit 1 }
    eof { send_user "\nSSH failure for hostname\n"; exit 1 }
    "*-> $"
    }

sleep 2


send "conf t\n"
expect "#"
send "hostname $newname\n"
expect "#"
send "exit\n"
expect "(config)#"
send "write mem\n"
expect "*#"
send "exit\n"
expect ":~\$" exit

# Announce which device we are working on and at what time
 send_user "\n"
 send_user ">>>>> Done working on $hostname @ [exec date] <<<<<\r"
 send_user "\n"

}
```

Here is my csv file

**hostnames.csv**

```
10.10.1.1,newhostname1
172.16.1.2,newhostname2
192.168.45.150,newhostname3
```

I would appreciate any assistance.

Thank you

Hi Dinesh

Thank you for your response.

I used the first code you provide without the "handle" part. It will now go to the next ip address if there's a failure with a login, but, it doesn't run my commands on a good login. The login to 172.16.1.2 is the only working connection. The others are to test the failover.

```
$**expect hostnames.exp** 
10.10.1.1
newhostname1

>>>>> Working on 10.10.1.1 @ Wed Oct  1 11:59:09 SAST 2014 <<<<<
spawn clogin 10.10.1.1
10.10.1.1

in /home/*****/.cloginrc.0.1.1

SSH failure for hostname for 10.10.1.1
172.16.1.2
newhostname2

>>>>> Working on 172.16.1.2 @ Wed Oct  1 11:59:09 SAST 2014 <<<<<
spawn clogin 172.16.1.2
172.16.1.2
spawn telnet 172.16.1.2
Trying 172.16.1.2...
.onnected to 172.16.1.2
Escape character is '^]'.

User Access Verification

Username: *****
Password: 
SR_Test_SW#
SR_Test_SW#
Failed to get login prompt for 172.16.1.2
192.168.45.150
newhostname3

>>>>> Working on 192.168.45.150 @ Wed Oct  1 11:59:11 SAST 2014 <<<<<
spawn clogin 192.168.45.150
192.168.45.150
spawn telnet 192.168.45.150
Trying 192.168.45.150...

Failed to get login prompt for 192.168.45.150
$
```

I did try your second code with the "handle" section, and that also gave me errors.

I'll provide you with an output if you need me to.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I made a change to the first code section and replaced **"*-> $"** part with **"*#" {}** It seems to be all good now. Thank you.

Comment: @ Evan van Zyl , Yes, update the error output in my answers comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `continue` under the expect for `timeout` and `eof`, instead of `exit 1`

```
expect {
    timeout  { 
              send_user "\n Failed to get login prompt for the switch $hostname\n"  
              continue 
             }
    eof { 
          send_user "\nSSH failure for hostname for the switch $hostname\n"
          continue 
        }
    "*-> $"
}
```

An example illustration as below.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 3
send_user "we are waiting for the word 'hi' \n"

#Looping for 10 times
foreach x { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10} {
        puts "Is anybody there???"
        expect  {
                timeout {
                        puts "Nobody responding to me at trial $x"
                        puts "I'm waiting"
                        #Proceeding with the next element of the loop, using 'continue'
                        continue
                }
                #Dont bother about this 'nocase' keyword. ;)
                -nocase "hi" { puts "Hey friend!" }
        }
}
```

Since you are spawning the 'clogin' even before the `expect`, we are safe in that aspect and it wont cause any problem. If it is unable to reach, we are going to continue with spawning of new 'clogin'.

But, it is good practice to close the spawned process gracefully. That can be arranged as

```
# After this command execution, the variable 'handle' will hold 
# the spawn handle reference for the 'clogin' process
set handle [ spawn clogin "$hostname\r" ] 

# Your expect statements here - Just modifying it for our needs

expect {
        timeout  { 
                  send_user "\n Failed to get login prompt for the switch $hostname\n"  
                  # Closing the process gracefully 
                  close $handle
                  continue 
                 }
        eof { 
              send_user "\nSSH failure for hostname for the switch $hostname\n"
              close $handle
              continue 
            }
        "*-> $"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on a search to find something like this script, except that it would execute in a third of the time. So, how would you go about taking the list, splitting it into three files/parts, and then execute the changes during three different sessions. Thus completing sooner.

Comment: Have a look at this link..: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508076/spawn-multiple-telnet-with-tcl-and-log-the-output-seperately)